# How do I reference the CPP Rest SDK in a native app?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, casablanca

I've got Visual Studio 2013 installed, it appears to come with a CPP Rest Extension SDK. The documentation explains how I can reference it in a Store App, but I want to use it from a native app. The headers don't seem to be immediately available, is there a standard way of referencing Extension SDKs for use in native apps?

---

I've seen here http://casablanca.codeplex.com/documentation there is a link for how to add a reference to a Win8 Store App. It also explains how to use NuGet, but I don't want to use NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I was getting confused by the Extension SDK that is for Store Apps, it looks like I missed this path:

```
P:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Cpp REST SDK for Visual Studio 2013
```